# Proving $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx$ $\le$ $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(x)|^2dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-transform

I have this question in my homework.

I've been trying to solve it for a while now, But couldn't get much further.

Let $f(x)$ be a function with period of $2 \pi$.

**Define**:

$f''(x) + f(x+\frac{\pi}{2}) = g(x)$

**Prove**:
$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f(x)|^2dx$ $\le$ $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|g(x)|^2dx$

Any hints/Assistance will be useful.

Comment: Hint: what is the Fourier series of $g$ in terms of $\hat{f}_k$, the Fourier coefficients of $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that $f''$ is continuous (weaker assumptions may be made), if $f(x)= \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_n e^{-inx}$, where
$$c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 f(s)e^{-ins}\,ds,$$
then
$$f'' (x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(in)^2c_n e^{-i n x}=-\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}n^2c_ne^{-inx}$$
This can be done by integration by parts and the use of the fundamental theorem of Calculus.
On the other hand, if $\tau_{a}f(x):=f(x-a)$, then
$$\tau_af(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-ina}c_n e^{-inx}$$
This can be seen using the periodicity of $f$ and a translation.

Then
$$g(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}((i)^n-n^2)c_n e^{-inx}$$

- For $n\in\{1,3\}\mod 4$, $|((i)^n-n^2)c_n|^2=(1+n^2)|c_n|^2>|c_n|^2$,
- For $n\equiv 2\mod 4$, $|((i)^n-n^2)c_n|^2=(n^2+1)^2|c_n|^2>|c_n|^2$,
- For $n\equiv0\mod 4$, $|((i)^n-n^2)c_n|^2=(n^2-1)^2|c_n|^2\geq|c_n|^2$.